# How to get rid of the decimal point in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

For example, I wanted to convert 0.5 into 05, 0.25 to 025, how could I do that?

Comment: `str(0.5).replace(".", "")`

Comment: @anupsabraham put that in an answer, comments are for asking for clarification

Comment: Sorry. Yeah. Doing it. Was not really sure that is the complete question and whether it would help others since the answer sounded too simple.

Comment: Well, it's a simple answer. I'd put something like "convert the number to a string, then rice all the periods:" above the code to make it feel "complete".  Edit: oh, well, my excuse is that I didn't reload the page.

Comment: Just did that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply convert the floating point number to string and then remove the `.` from the string

```
number = 0.5
print str(number).replace(".", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a string you can use this:

```
str(0.5).replace('.','')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replace()` function replaces a character in a string with something else:
e.g.

```
print('>>> 12345'.replace('1','0'))
```

would print:

```
>>> 02345
```

The replace function has two parameters, which are:
 `replace(what you are replacing, what it is changed to)`

so your answer would be:
 `print(str(0.5).replace('.',''))`